# python regex - matching names with findall()

Tags: python, regex, findall

I am trying to extract all instances of last names in a text, but the following expression is only getting me Mr. Mrs. or Miss without the name after it. 
What is wrong with my python regex?

```
surnames = re.findall(r'(Mrs\. |Mr\. |Miss )[A-Z][a-z]+', text.read())
```

returns:

```
['Mr. ', 'Mr. ', 'Mrs. ', 'Mr. ',.....
```

Comment: `r'(?:Mrs\. |Mr\. |Miss )[A-Z][a-z]+'`

Comment: thanks that fixed it - what does ?: do?

Comment: With negative lookahead shall works... (?!Mrs\. |Mr\. |Miss )[A-Z][a-z]+